# Are Spring Cloud starter dependencies curated?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

In a test project I need to include `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` as a dependency, and the dependencyConvergence enforcer rule failed as shown below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.3.0:enforce (enforce-dependencyConvergence) on project prueba-springboot:
[ERROR] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
[ERROR] Failed while enforcing releasability.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Dependency convergence error for com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.5.3 paths to dependency are:
[ERROR] +-consejo.prueba:prueba-springboot:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]   +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:4.0.3:compile
[ERROR]     +-com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:2.0.1:compile
[ERROR]       +-com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:compile
[ERROR]         +-com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.5.3:runtime
[ERROR] and
[ERROR] +-consejo.prueba:prueba-springboot:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]   +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:4.0.3:compile
[ERROR]     +-com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:2.0.1:compile
[ERROR]       +-com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.12.21:compile
```

As I understood the Spring Boot dependencies are "curated" (in the sense they are tested to work well I guess).
The question is if this is also true for Spring Cloud project starters, and in this case this should be considered a bug? or are the starters provided as is and is up to the user to choose which version of dependencies to use? (in this case servo-core 0.5.3 vs 0.12.21)

Comment: Yes, but those are defined in Netflix projects, not spring cloud

Comment: Of course, but they could pick one of the versiones and exclude it, or pick one and added in the <dependencyManagement>. If you see the [pom](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client/4.0.3/overview) you can see that they excluded several dependencies already.